# Is letter-writing still on topic?

Tags: discussion, on-topic-off-topic

**Is the** [letter-writing](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/letter-writing) **tag still something we want to do?**

[This answer](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10062/is-the-email-tag-obsolete/10069) says that [letter-writing](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/letter-writing) is more on-topic than the [email](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/email) tag, but that was 2 years ago, and [Interpersonal Skills](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/) started as public beta [around 2 years ago too](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/92736/interpersonal-skills).

My opinion is that most of the [letter-writing](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/letter-writing) questions could be more on topic on Interpersonal or Workplace SE sites.

---

#### Stats

- [166 Questions](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/letter-writing)
- [67 Closed](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?tab=Relevance&pagesize=15&q=%5bletter-writing%5d+closed%3ayes)
- [85 with 0 or less votes](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?tab=Relevance&pagesize=15&q=%5bletter-writing%5d+is%3aquestion+score%3a..0)

---

- Are there any questions that are on topic here that wouldn't be on Interpersonal or Workplace?
- Is the the tag generally on topic with the site these days?

Comment: It seems like it's almost always going to be about writing advice which would almost always be opinion based. But I don't see a glut of these being problematic lately. Is there harm in allowing it to stay?

Comment: @Mitch we've had 3 this month, [this one](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/509664/how-to-write-an-email-to-reminder-my-professor-to-write-recommendation-letter-fo) made me think of it

Comment: @Mitch this isn't a `burninate-request` (yet). I'm curious about whether it is relevant - if people think not, then it could escalate.

Comment: Re 3 this month - for roughly 2 per month over the life of ELU, some clumping and some sparseness are not unexpected. Re burninating or rather its flipside, auto-closing of questions that would have such a tag, I don't think its on the level of "IELTS" or "Is this grammatical?" whatever the tags) which are almost automatically closable.

Comment: @Mitch fair enough. `grammar` 

Comment: @Mitch the `[grammaticality]` tag is still a thing, right? It has over 5,000 questions.

Comment: @JJJ Sure it's a popular tag, and a very reasonable and logical one for this site, but any question that starts out "Is this grammatical?" is already going down a pathway that is unlikely to be a good one. First, such a titled question is most likely going to be more relevant to ELL, and for them probably closable too. Just my feelings about things.